# class instantiation from the main or through a method

Tags: c#

I know this is too silly a question. But I am a learner and class business is difficult for me.

I am presenting Code-1 and below that Code-2. I would like to know if both serves the same purpose and the difference exists only in the presentation.

I raise this doubt because up to this point I used to do everything in the main rather than have a different method within the class Program.

Code-1.

```
namespace trial1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.InstanceEqual();
        }
        public void InstanceEqual()
        {
            string name = "Unnikrishnan";
            employeename emp1 = new employeename(name);
        }
    }
    public class employeename
    {
        string _name;
        public employeename(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Code-2.

```
namespace trial1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            employeename emp1 = new employeename("Unnikrishnan");
        }
    }
    public class employeename
    {
        string _name;
        public employeename(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I the only one who read this 10 times and didn't get what OP is talking about?

Comment: Only the OP has viewed it to find if any answer is there!

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking here? Is there a specific problem?

Comment: can you ask explicitly straight? you are not chatting. you are asking a question!

Comment: I mean the public void Instance() serves the same purpose as the 2nd line in static void main() without any difference?

Comment: I will edit my question.

Comment: IMO its not good to create an instance of Program and access its non static methods. just make them static methods and access them directly. `InstanceEqual();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but I'll go for it.

You are certainly allowed to have a method in the Program class, though typically you wouldn't for any program beyond a test or homework.

The two lines *do not* accomplish the same thing. Let's compare what they do:

```
employeename emp1 = new employeename("Joe");
```

This line creates a new variable emp1 with a new employeename object. This variable is in scope only in the main function. The next line calls the InstanceEqual method:

```
public void InstanceEqual()
{
    string name = "Unnikrishnan";
    employeename emp1 = new employeename(name);
}
```

The method creates a new variable called emp1 that is in scope only in the `InstanceEqual` method. Once the `InstanceEqual` method is finished, it returns control to `main()` and you no longer can access the emp1 that you created in the `InstanceEqual` method.

If you want to accomplish the same thing, you mush *return* that value you created. A different version to accomplish the same thing would look like this:

```
namespace trial1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            employeename emp1 = new employeename("Joe");
            employeename emp2 = p.InstanceEqual();
        }
        public employeename InstanceEqual()
        {
            string name = "Unnikrishnan";
            employeename emp2 = new employeename(name);
            return emp2;
        }
    }
    public class employeename
    {
        string _name;
        public employeename(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have poured a little knowledge into my brain. Thank you very much. I accept the answer.

Comment: anything specific not making sense?

Comment: I love the way you have illustrated the solution. But I desire also to know if I can receive back the string value in the Main. That should satisfy me. @Scott M.

Comment: You can access it by `emp2._name`

Comment: Yes. I tested the very same code you have written above after making the string _name public. Or else 'inaccessible due to its protection level' error is coming up. thanks.